# c# access database update value

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

i tried update a data value like that

```
 OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
 Source=.\botbase.accdb");
  private void metroButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            baglanti.Open();
            OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand("Update TBL_BOT set botname=@p1, botpass=@p2,botcha=@p3 where botid = @p4 ", baglanti);
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", metroTextBox6.Text);
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", metroTextBox3.Text);
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", metroTextBox4.Text);
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", metroTextBox5.Text);
            komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
            baglanti.Close();



        }
```

when I run it. There is a error like that

[image]

Comment: connection works fine.

Comment: As I recall access does not support named parameters. Try changing your query to "Update [TBL_BOT] set [botname]=?, [botpass]=?, [botcha]=? where [botid]=?" then add the parameters `Parameters.AddWithValue()` in the proper order.

Comment: uh but how can i order a value when its ?. is it like that komut.parameters.addwithvalue(botname, "value" );

Answer (score 0):

You might need to pass in the data type.  Something like this:

````
      public  AddressVerify AddVerify(ref AddressVerify thisAddress)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "verifyAddress";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = thisAddress.city;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = thisAddress.state;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@zipCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = thisAddress.zipCode;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    thisAddress.Status = (string)(reader["Status"]);
                }//while
                reader.Close();
            }//using
            return thisAddress;
        }//AddVerify```
````

Comment: i do not have any problem when i tried read it. i can read access database also insert and delete. but when i try update value

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the parameters order from @p1 to @p4:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\tomas.paul\Documents\botbase.accdb"))
    using (OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand("Update TBL_BOT set botname=@p1, botpass=@p2,botcha=@p3 where botid = @p4", baglanti))
    {
        baglanti.Open();
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "parameter 1");
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", "parameter 2");
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", "parameter 3");
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", "1");
        komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
        baglanti.Close();
    }
}
```

This works for me. I've added the execution code into recommended using blocks.

Answer (score 0):

yes thx for everyone I wasted ur time :( sorry.

i was writing wrong header text :D botname must be botacc :D